# Reconnect to Neo4j REST Service

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I got a usecase where a user can connect to different neo4j databases. I'm using spring data. My configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.inno")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("org.inno.dao")
public class AppConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    public AppConfig() {
       setBasePackage("org.inno.model");
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
       //url may change based on the user preferences
       String url = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/"; 
       return new SpringRestGraphDatabase(url);
    }
}
```

I use the GraphDatabaseService for a repository.

**My question:** How can I connect to a different database at runtime? I'm not talking about startup of the application. There I can use the Preferences API. I'm talking about a usecase where I'm already connected to a server but want to switch to another one. Unfortunately the service offers a shutdown method only, but nothing to reconnect to another URL. Do I have to destroy the bean of the GraphDatabaseService by accessing the ApplicationContext? Or is there another way?

Comment: You can just define as second bean with the second URL. You should probably also use SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase

Comment: Yes, I know that the SpringRestGraphDatabase is deprecated, it is only a sample. But your propose means I could only switch do a different URL once.

Answer (score 0):

What's your actual use-case?

You can instantiate also a `Neo4jTemplate` directly passing it an instance of `SpringRestGraphDatabase` in the constructor.

Comment: I have a client where the user can enter any url in a dialog and can save the graph without restarting the client. I followed only the tutorials @ spring-data-neo4j, where the repository is created with proxies. I had no clue about the template yet. Maybe it is a solution.